# How to pass token data and render a template in Django at once?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have a login form that redirects a user to a certain page in my application. But before this happens, I used JWT tokens (via Simple-JWT library) and need to store these tokens within my Javascript code (in order to access each page after logging in). I am completely new to using tokens and don't know how to store them. How can I do this?

This is what I had done before:

**views.py:**

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            username = login_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = login_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            new_user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
            if new_user is not None:
                url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/token/' 
                values = {
                    'username' : username,
                    'password' : password
                }
                r = requests.post(url, data = values) 
                token_data = r.json()
                return Response(token_data, template_name='users/interface.html') #interface is the template which is seen after logging in successfully.
    else:
        login_form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, "users/login.html", {"login_form" : login_form})
```

**Currently, I am getting this error:**

```
AssertionError at /login/
.accepted_renderer not set on Response
```

How can I pass the token data to my JS file and render the 'interface' template at once? Should I use AJAX for this? Or, is there any other efficient solution out there? Thank you very much.

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: I just stay on the login page. That's all. No errors are shown in my terminal.

Comment: check if your login function working

Comment: I changed my question and would love to hear your answer.